# BCP Utility import with XML

Tags: sql, database, import, bcp

I was told to research BCP Utility to figure out how to import an XML file into a SQL table, but as far as I can see it's not a feature of BCP Utility and that csv files are pretty much the go to if that's necessary. All I see with XML files is how to create and use formatting files, but nothing about actually bulk loading data with XML files.

As for my question...is it possible? Can you use an XML file and push that straight to a table? And if it isn't possible with BCP Utility is there anything that has that functionality?

Thanks.

Comment: go through this post https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/working-with-the-bcp-command-line-utility/

Comment: @vkp Ya I combed through that and the only thing I could find relating to XML files were formatting files, but nothing with importing data.